# How to avoid duplicates while looping through a sorted mongodb cursor

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I try to avoid having duplicates returned by a mongodb cursor when write operations occurs while looping through documents.

The following code will loop for ever as we modifiy the updatedAt date while reading the collection.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');

const Model = mongoose.model(
    'Cat', 
    mongoose.Schema({ name: String }, { timestamps: true }).index({ updatedAt: 1 })
);

mongoose
    .connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useMongoClient: true })
    .then(() => {
        const docs = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            docs.push({ name: i });
        }
        return Model.insertMany(docs)
    })
    .then(() => {
        const c = Model.find({}).sort({ updatedAt: 1 }).cursor();

        return c.eachAsync((doc) => {
            doc.markModified('name');
            console.log(doc.name);
            return doc.save();
        });
    });
```

I tried to use `cursor.snapshot()` and it works well but it cannot be used on a sorted query.

The only alternative I found is to send a count request first then apply a limit to the cursor without using snapshot at all. This seems to work as mongo seems to stack up modified document FIFO style.
The problem is that document can be inserted between the count and the cursor queries which leads to incomplete data returned by the cursor.

How can I loop through a cursor, using a sorted query without ending up with duplicates documents?

Comment: `Model.updateMany({},{ "$currentDate": { "updatedAt": true } })` No need to return every document just to make a change. That's an anti-pattern, really inefficient and very dangerous. Also `eachAsync()` is not doing what you think it is anyway. Not how you iterate a cursor, but you simply don't need to.

Comment: @NeilLunn This is just an example to illustrate the issue. In real life, I am not actually just bumping the updatedAt field, I am processing imported documents, updating the document according to the result of that process and emitting an event. The process has to be done document by document. Can you elaborate on what `eachAsync()` is doing or add some links?